# Why does updating an HTML <object> tag's data attribute cause the error "TypeError: document.body is null"

Tags: javascript, svg, firefox

I'm trying to dynamically add SVG elements to a page but when I change the `data` attribute of the HTML `object` element a console error pops up that I am unable to trap with `try {} catch () {}`. Here is a reduced example showing the behavior I am experiencing:

```js
function init() {
  const obj = document.createElement("object")

  obj.setAttribute("data", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e8/Svg_example3.svg")
  obj.setAttribute("type", "image/svg+xml")

  document.body.append(obj)
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init)
```

This is only happening in Firefox for me; Chrome and Safari work fine without error.

The error happens in this CodePen, not in the above snippet:

https://codepen.io/kalisjoshua/pen/dyWwBbR

The error I am see is:

[image]

Comment: Put the code here, not codepen. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: The snippet works fine for me in Firefox. Try turning off plugins.

Comment: Why are you embedding `<object>` instead of `<img src="...">` though?

Comment: The snippet seems to work just fine in Chrome also.

Comment: Using an <object> instead of an <img> allows for interactivity; In my actual use case I have a `:hover` css rule that requires the interactivity of <object>. @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: The snippet is a great idea @Barmar. Thank you. However it isn't exhibiting the behavior. The CodePen does show that it is throwing an error. Would it be OK to also include the link to CodePen?

Comment: I've added back the codepen link. But I tried it in FF and don't see an error.

Comment: Please add the precise error to the question.